# C++11 trailing return member function using decltype and constness

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, decltype, type-deduction

I am trying to understand the trailing return based new function declaration syntax in C++11, using decltype.

In the following code, I am trying to define a member function returning a const & to allow for **read-only access** to `i`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    int &i;

    X(int &ii) : i(ii) {}

//    auto acc() const -> std::add_const<decltype((i))>::type { return i; } // fails the constness test
    auto acc() const -> decltype(i) { return i; } // fails the constness test
//    const int &acc() const { return i; } // works as expected   
};

void modify_const(const X &v) {
    v.acc() = 1;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    X x(i);

    modify_const(x);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, only the last commented version of `acc()` works, whereas using the others, the code just compiles and prints value `1`.

**Question**: How do we have to define the `acc()` function using the new function declaration syntax based on `decltype`, such that the compilation here fails due to returning a `const &int` in `modify_const`, or in other words, such that `acc()` has a proper `const &int` return type.

**Remark**: using `int i;` instead of `int &i;` as the member variable in `X` produces a compile error, as expected.

**Edited** to better distinguish between constness of `v` and `X::i`, respectively. It is the latter I am trying to impose in `acc()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `decltype((i))` return `int&` and apply `const` to that type has no effect. You want something like

```
template <typename T> struct add_ref_const { typedef T const type; };
template <typename T> struct add_ref_const<T&> { typedef T const& type; };
```

... and then use

```
auto acc() const -> typename add_ref_const<decltype((i))>::type { return i; }
```

That is, the `const` needs to go between the type `T` and the `&`. The solution would have been obvious if you had put the `const` into the correct location: [`const` should go to the right](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/).

Comment: What also works in this particular case is 
`auto acc() const -> decltype(i) const& { return i; }` 
I'm just wondering what is the proper way to implement it, since your suggestion requires additional trait support. This is fine, but why are the `add_ref_const` structs not available in the std lib in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing illegal about a `const` member function modifying the target of a pointer to non-const, even if that pointer was gotten from a member variable.

From the compiler's perspective, `int&` IS the correct return type.

Your "`modify_const`" function is incorrectly named.  `i` is what gets modified, and is not `const`.

Comment: I see your point, I edited my post to make it more clear that my goal is actually to have a **read-only access** to `i`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an & to the left and skip the trailing return type.

```
struct X {
    int &i;

    X(int &ii) : i(ii) {}

    auto& acc() const { return i; } // Returns const reference
    auto& acc() { return i; } // Returns non-const reference
    const auto& acc() const { return i; } // Add const to the left to make it even more readable
};
```

Note that using this syntax you can declare the member variable after you have declared the function.